# dynamically generated data not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have link, when an user clicks, it appends the data into a div like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="StartMesssage()">
    <span class="font-icon fa fa-pencil"></span>
</a> 

<script>
    function StartMesssage(){ 
        $(".div1").append(
            '<section class="chat-area d2"><div class="chat-area-in"><input type="text" class="form-control spinner" id="to-message"  data-mt-filter-control /> </div></section>'
        ); 
    } 
</script>
```

Now the problem I'm facing is that `data-mt-filter-control` is a jQuery plugin when I get HTML tags dynamically it doesn't work but if I add these tags into my HTML

```
<section class="chat-area d2">
    <div class="chat-area-in">
        <input type="text" class="form-control spinner" id="to-message"  data-mt-filter-control />
    </div>
</section>
```

and refresh my page, then it works

Comment: You have to update or re-initiate the plugin.

Comment: @Burimi i don't find any way to initiate this plugin, how can i achieve this?

Comment: i appended the plugin too <script src="https://cdn.example.com/js/jquery-mt-select.min.js"><\/script> now it's working any other way too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Event driven plugin's normally has an init method that runs on page load.

After adding content dynamically you likely need to call that init method again, or else their event's is not called/fired on those dynamic added elements.